# Ruby retry statement

Tags: ruby

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm) and read until `loops`. From the tutorial, I expected to get:

> ```
> Value of local variable is 1
> Value of local variable is 2
> Value of local variable is 1
> Value of local variable is 2
> Value of local variable is 1
> Value of local variable is 2
> ............................
> ```

but I get this instead

```
Value of local variable is 0
Value of local variable is 1
Value of local variable is 2
```

This is the code I use, which exactly same with the tutorial

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

for i in 0..5
  retry if i > 2
  puts "Value of local variable is #{i}"
end
```

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Here is the doc for the keyword [retry](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/keywords_rdoc.html). [Here](https://blog.appsignal.com/2018/06/05/redo-retry-next.html) is one of many articles that explains its use. You will see that `retry` is only used after an exception has occurred.

Comment: Which version of Ruby are you using? `retry` stopped working on loops in 1.9, and if there’s nothing else around it should be an error on 2.5.

Comment: @Ry- ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

Comment: @Ry- Check the [second page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_overview.htm), it is talking about 1.8.5.

Comment: @muistooshort thanks for pointing out the version.I never think of the different version will give different result

Comment: @muistooshort: Sorry, I was asking about the OP’s Ruby version, not the tutorial’s.

Comment: You can find some good Ruby resources on the [Ruby community website](https://ruby-community.com/pages/links). This includes resources for learning Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have stated, `retry` is limited to `rescue` blocks now.  If you want to re-produce your example, you'll have to wrap it in a begin...rescue:

```
begin
  for i in 0..5
    raise "too big" if i > 2
    puts "Value of local variable is #{i}"
  end
rescue
  retry
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed this: from The Ruby Programming Language, (a book from 2008, co-authored by Matz, which covers Ruby 1.8 and 1.9):"(...) In Ruby 1.8 however, `retry` has another use: it starts an iterator based iteration (or any method invocation) from the beginning. This use of the `retry` statement is extremely rare, and has been removed from the language in Ruby 1.9. It should, therefor, be considered a deprecated language feature and should not be used in new code."(page 152).
Running OP's code results in a syntax error, at least since Ruby 2.3.
`Invalid retry (SyntaxError)`